# How is it possible to be part of the private beta for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, private-beta

I've noticed the *beta* badge on Stack Overflow.

Is the participation open? How is it possible to be part of the *private* beta?

Comment: Miss you `closed as no longer relevant`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its [description](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/30/beta) is just *Actively participated in the Stack Overflow private beta*.

Maybe Jeff et al are willing to grant it for actively participating in the [Stack Overflow *API* private beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/stack-overflow-api-private-beta-starts/) as well...

Comment: I would like to see a different badge awarded for participation in that.

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't notice the **participated**, taking it for **partecipating**. When I've seen the badge, I imagined a private *dev* version was still in progress. +1 and accepting the answer for not using irony in your answer with this poor guy :)

Answer (score 32):

The private beta was before [September 15th, 2008](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/then-a-miracle-occurs-public-beta/).

Physicists are still working on whether it's possible to become part of it.

Answer (score 14):

Just find yourself one of these:

[image: TARDIS]

Comment: The 60's cop inside might get annoyed.

Comment: Totally offtopic, but to my great surprise, I *like* the new doctor!

Comment: I can't stand Doctor Who. None of the 12 episodes I've seen are any good.

Comment: @mmyers: try to find some of the Tom Baker episodes. Also, try to watch them while you're about 10 years of age.

Comment: @Shog9: Maybe that's my problem: I've only seen new ones. (I don't think I've ever managed to watch an entire episode straight through.)

Comment: @json: er, why do you think there'd be a police man in there? It would appear that this thing is actually just a phone booth that only works for calling 999, based on the words "public call" in between "police" and "box"...

Comment: I'm with Pekka. Except for flying Daleks. Flying Daleks are a myth. And an abomination.

Comment: @SamB because it's not like a phone booth. A police box has two phones - on the inside of the *locked* door is a phone for a policeman on duty to call the station (this is from before walkie talkies). Eventually an outside phone was also added (it's on the other side), which allowed for the public to call the police.

Comment: Where is the image? Please post it again...

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way you might be able to at least get the beta *badge* and make people *think* you were part of the private beta:

- Find a user who made an account during the private beta period but doesn't want it or use it anymore.
- Convince them to give you control of the account.
- Convince a moderator to merge your current account into the older one.
- ???
- Beta Badge!

Comment: I think you misspelled *profit*.

Comment: @Aarobot I don't see the word profit at all...

Comment: @KonradViltersten: I think you misspelled the sentence, it should read "I don't think I got the joke". :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters Bazinga and/or woosh on me.

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  The beta period is long over.