# How to earn Precognitive badge

Tags: discussion, badges, area-51

I registered in the [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)  and followed some of the Interested Technologies but still not able to get Precognitive badge.

Comment: @Bart nope, see [here](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/help/badges/66/precognitive) for example. The first batch of badges were given at mar 29 '11 at 22:23 and the site entered its Private Beta in that day at 19:00 according to [the Area51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4861/parenting).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ah dammit, you're right. I'll go get my coffee now and delete this...

Comment: @Bart who'll update [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)? :-)

Comment: You @ShaWizDowArd */me runs*

Comment: Also related (possible duplicate of your next question): [Do I have any chance now to get a beta badge for stack overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190826), [How is it possible to be part of the private beta for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45848)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Precognitive](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/131/precognitive) badge is awarded to the user when he follows for a proposal of a site in [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

But you will get the badge only after the site enters its private beta phase.

You can also have a look at the answer to the simillar question by [oded](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140505/oded) on
[Precognitive Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146407/precognitive-badge/146408#146408)

It will help you to clear the doubts of getting the Precognitive Badge for the Area51 site.